# How can I install Python Packages to MAMP Python installation or get MAMP to use a local installation or virtual environment?

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv, mamp

I am using MAMP on Mac as my local host. I want to run python scrips on it (pyscript). I can get the python code to run in visual studio code. But when I open the code on my local host, the modules can't be accessed, because MAMP uses the python installation in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/python Is there anyway I can either access the MAMP Python installation (update it and install packages) or get MAMP to use a different Pyton installation or environment? Any help is greatly appreciated!

So far I have tried to change the interpeter in Visual Studio code. If I chose a venv that I created for my workspace, I can install packages through the terminal to this venv. If I choose a different interpreter, I can do that for that interpreter as well. Only when I manually enter the path to the MAMP installation, the termial (I opened a new one) is still acessing the previously chosen one. I checked that by typing `which python` I have also gone over every Stackoverflow question that includes MAMP and python.